# Kotlin - Mockito cannot mock/spy (Spring REST API)

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, mocking, kotlin

Since all classes in Kotlin are `final` by default, and Mockito can't spy on final classes:

```
Cannot mock/spy class bye.persistence.jdbcTrial
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
```

And [this guide](https://medium.com/@dpreussler/never-say-final-mocking-kotlin-classes-in-unit-tests-314d275b82b1#.tcjetb1tz)
(6 July, Danny Preussler) is saying that a framework is neccessary to resolve this issue.

Now was I wondering, is it possible to test a REST API (using Spring MockMvc). Below is my tester code:

```
package byeTest.persistenceTest
import bye.domain.User
import bye.persistence.jdbcTrial
import bye.spring.GreetingController
import byeTest.persistenceTest.RestAPITest.RootConfig
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.BDDMockito.given
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(RootConfig::class))
@WebAppConfiguration
open class RestAPITest {
    var mockMvc: MockMvc? = null;

    @Autowired
    var wac : WebApplicationContext? = null;

    @Autowired
    var jdbcTrial : jdbcTrial? = null

    @Autowired
    var todoServiceMock : GreetingController? = null;

    @Before
    open fun setup(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build()
        given(this.jdbcTrial?.getUserById(2)).willReturn(User(2,"uname","typ"));

    }



    @Test
    open public fun find_2(){
        mockMvc!!.perform(get("/user/2").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

            .andExpect(content().string("{\"id\":2,\"username\":\"uname\",\"usertype\":\"typ\"}"))


    }

    @Configuration
    open class RootConfig{
        @Bean
        open fun jdbcTrial():jdbcTrial{
            return Mockito.mock(jdbcTrial::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

I set all the functions and classes used to `open` since according to the [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance) this is the exact opposite of `final`. But using this (everywhere) still throws the exception mentioned above.

```
import bye.domain.Comment
import bye.domain.Event
import bye.domain.Participant
import bye.domain.User
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.Statement
import java.util.ArrayList
import javax.sql.DataSource

open class jdbcTrial() {
    open var url: String = "jdbc:postgresql://rosdel.quintor.local:5432/quintorevents"
    //val props: Properties = Properties();

    open var DB_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    open var dataSource:String? = "b";

    constructor(s : String):this(){
        this.dataSource = s
    }

    open fun getFoo():String{
        var query : String = "select val_col from foo_tbl where key_col = 'foo';"
        var rs:ResultSet = this.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(query)
        var result:String = "wrong";
        while(rs.next()){
            result= rs.getString("val_col")
        }
        return result;
    }

    open fun getBaz():String{
        return "qux"
    }

    // /events
    open fun getAll(): List<Event> {
        return getMultipleEvents("select * from quintor_event;")
    }

    // /events/search
    open fun searchEvents(search: String): List<Event> {
        var query = "select * from quintor_event where title LIKE '%" + search + "%';"
        return getMultipleEvents(query)
    }

    // used for getting the comments
    open fun getUserById(id: Int): User {
        var query = "select * from quintor_user where id = ${id};";
        return getSingleUser(query)
    }
    ........
```

Comment: Note that the `jdbcTrial` class needs to marked `open` to be able to mock it. Since you didn't include this class, we can't be sure of the problem.

Comment: I added a bit of the class, it's quite a huge class atm, but you can conclude that every other function is set up the same

Comment: If I copy the `jdbcTrial` class and remove the methods that do not compile I am perfectly able to mock it using `Mockito.mock(jdbcTrial::class.java)`.

Comment: And I get `Cannot mock/spy class bye.persistence.jdbcTrial
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
 at byeTest.persistenceTest.RestAPITest$RootConfig.jdbcTrial(RestAPITest.kt:60)`

Comment: Try copying the `jdbcTrial` class you posted here, remove the `getUserById`, `searchEvents`, `getAll` and `getFoo()` methods, and try again? If that works, you may have removed too much.

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: I think you should reconsider your testing strategy. Rather than mocking the `jdbcTrial` class (and doing the awful thing of marking it `open`), let your tests use it normally. Write an integration test, populating the db with the needed `User` data. I've written hundreds of tests like this; it's a much better approach than isolated unit tests, and I say this as someone who develops a Java mocking library which *does* mock `final` classes.

Comment: I already have a mocked database, this makes me able to test all the database functions. But I can't test the output of the REST API. You say that this doesn't matter and that testing only the database functions with a mocked DB is better?

Answer (score 0):

About mock final classes in kotlin – You can use mockito kotlin library. It is available on github. And in this link https://hadihariri.com/2016/10/04/Mocking-Kotlin-With-Mockito/ you can find out how to do it. I use it every day and I also use mockmvc from spring and it works fine.